# Is it possible to have my button run three separate functions based on what I have selected?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a unit converter with multiple selections for different units like KG > LBS, Celsius to Fahrenheit.

`document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', convert, false);`

I need that convert to change based on my selection within the html is this possible?

```
<form>
   <fieldset>
      <label for="fValue">
      Enter first value
      </label>
      <input type="number" id="fValue" />
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="conv" id="but1" onclick="but1();"> Temp
<br>
<input type="radio" name="conv" id="but2" onclick="but2();"> Distance
<br>
<input type="radio" name="conv" id="but3"> Weight
</form>
<button type="button" id="button">Convert to</button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <p>Results</p>
   <p id="cValue">&nbsp;</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: The *convert* function should accept parameters to know what units to convert from and to.

Comment: Whatever you do, you're going to be passing a function as the event listener. So whatever kind of switching you do will take place inside that function, for example inside your `convert`. So in your basic studies of the language, I'm sure you learned about `if/else` statements, and so you should utilize that knowledge to do what you want.

Comment: Post more of your code. How is the user making selection?

Comment: @skyline3000 Via radio buttons in html.

Comment: Post your HTML code

Comment: @skyline3000 I updated the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just assign your button's event listener a function that checks what is selected in your HTML and then call another function that will do the math you want.

```
function checkSelection() {
  // Where selection* is whatever you want to check for.
  if(selection1){
     do_math_1();
  }
  else if(selection2 and selection3) {
    do_math_2();
  }
  else {
    do_math_3();
  }
}

funcion do_math_1(){
  // Whatever you want to do.
}

funcion do_math_2(){
  // Whatever you want to do.
}

funcion do_math_3(){
  // Whatever you want to do.
}
```

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', checkSelection);

Comment: @John: On what point are you lost? If you don't know where to begin, then the place to start would be in a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: @patrickdamery So I can have it check which radio button has been selected and have it call the appropriate function based on that?

Comment: I have three radio buttons, all three do separate conversions and I need to change html on the page with each one which is easy enough to do but I'm having problems with having the function check which one the user selected and make the button call the correct function.

Comment: @John I recommend you learn how to use a framework like jQuery or something, it makes that kind of stuff super easy. But if you just want to use Vanilla Javascript then do this: document.getElementById('button_Id').checked

Comment: I am open to using jQuery I have used it a bit in the past I just want to finish this the best way possible.

Comment: @John can't really tell you what the best possible way is as there is often more than 1 best possible way. More often than not the better choice is to work with whatever language(s) you are most comfortable with, however if you do have time to learn how to use it and implement it I would suggest using a framework as that would be much better than just using Vanilla Javascript. I don't know the scope of your project so just do some research on the different frameworks and decide which suits your needs best

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily directly have it within this line of JavaScript, but if you made a function that wrapped the three different functions (for example `function convertSelect() {}`) and called that, then within it you could check to see what is selected, and call the correct function.

You could make an anonymous function like `document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {...}, false);` if you wanted, but it would probably be wise to make it it's own function for clarity's sake.